# How to sum two columns based on another column condition in SAS and store the result in a variable

Tags: sql, sas

I have data like this :

```
ColumnA  ColumnB ColumnC
1        10       20
1        10       30
0        50       10
0        50       20
1        10       40
```

I want to sum values of ColumnB and ColumnC where the values of ColumnA = 1 and store the result in a variable
i.e. I want 120 (sum values of ColumnB and ColumnC where the values of ColumnA = 1) and store this result in a variable in SAS.

With this I also want to (sum values of ColumnB and ColumnC where the values of ColumnA = 0) in another variable i.e. 130 in another variable in SAS

I tried to create a variable in proc print, means,etc. and even thought of doing it in proc sql but was unable to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily done with basic SQL:

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input columnA columnB columnC;
datalines;
1 10 20
1 10 30
0 50 10
0 50 20
1 10 40
;
run;

proc sql;
  select sum(ColumnB)+sum(ColumnC)
  into: want
  from have
  where columnA=1
  ;
quit;

/* the result is stored in variable &want */

%put &want.;
```

EDIT: to answer your follow-up question, this will give you two output variables with the two sums:

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input columnA columnB columnC;
datalines;
1 10 20
1 10 30
0 50 10
0 50 20
1 10 40
;
run;

proc sql;
  select sum(case when columnA=1 then ColumnB+ColumnC end) as A0
        ,sum(case when columnA=0 then ColumnB+ColumnC end) as A1
  into: want0, :want1
  from have
  ;
quit;

/* variable &want1 contains the result where ColumnA=1 and &want2 where ColumnA=0 */
%put &want0;
%put &want1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply....It was helpful and working........Just to add in the same condition, I also want to sum values of ColumnB and ColumnC where the values of ColumnA = 0 in another variable in same query i.e. 130 in another variable in the same query....Can you also comment on how I can do that?

Comment: @ManojSrivastava you're welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure...I will accept the solution......Just to add in the same condition, I also want to sum values of ColumnB and ColumnC where the values of ColumnA = 0 in another variable in same query i.e. 130 in another variable in the same query....Can you also comment on how I can do that?

Comment: @ManojSrivastava I added a solution to your followup question in my original answer

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @user2877959  for your quick help...I appreciate it !!